# how to access uploaded file from web-browser in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-storage

This is what i have done to upload my file into in laravel project.

```
if($request->file()) {
     $fileName = time().'_'.$request->file('imageFile')->getClientOriginalName();
     $filePath = $request->file('imageFile')->storeAs('products', $fileName, 'public');
     $product->featured_image = '/storage/' . $filePath;
 }
```

**public disk**

```
'public' => [
      'driver' => 'local',
      'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
      'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
      'visibility' => 'public',
 ],
```

The file uploaded in storage folder inside app/public/products but when I try to retrieve my file showing 404 error. Even I have created the symbolic link with the public folder but not working.
i don't no why but files are not showing inside the public folder. files are only uploading project level or private folder inside storage folder. how I can access the file through a web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have create symbolic link

```
php aritsan storage:link
```

this will create shortcut storage folder in public folder

so you can access url

```
asset('storage/products/filename')
```

in your case it you need to change path while storing

```
  $product->featured_image =  $fileName;
```

so while accessing

```
 asset('storage/products/'.$product->featured_image )
```

ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: i have done the same everything you mention from start but not working in the public folder storage folder has created after the symbolic link creation but the files are not uploading in the public folder. all files are uploading inside the project storage folder. which is not accessible through web browser as I know

Comment: yes files uplaoding to storage folder and it automatically link to public folder.show the code how you display

Comment: $filePath = $request->file('imageFile')->move(public_path('storage/products'), $fileName); i just move the file into public directory is this the right thing I did. now I;m able to see it from web-browser

Comment: how you displaying image

Comment: keep your code same as in answer.its correct.dont change

Comment: i'm using vuejs on frontend

Comment: imageFile : this.product ? this.product.featured_image : null,

Comment: :style="{ 'background-image': `url(${imageFile})` }"

Comment: product.featured_image only get imagename so it should be  like https://urdomain.com/storage/products/+product.featured_image

Comment: no it's working now i just uploading the files directly into the public folder

Answer (score 0):

Per the doc - "To make these files accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic link from public/storage to storage/app/public"

`php artisan storage:link`

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem

Answer (score 0):

Running this on command prompt works for me:

```
rm public/storage
php artisan storage:link
```